# What is Mobile Sync - Backup and why is it taking so much space?

Tags: macos, finder, disk-space, storage, applications

I was checking my directory and found out that the Folder Backup in Library > Application Support > Mobile Sync > Backup, is taking 13GB of my Harddisk ... What is this and why is taking so much space .. Can I delete it ?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It's the folder where iTunes saves the backUps of your iDevice. And it takes so much space because each time you sync a device, previous backUps are not deleted.

Deleting the folder will, then, mean losing those backUps. Doing this regularly is advised for saving HD space. Just make sure to make a new backUp afterwards, and that you won't need those backUps.

You can do that through iTunes too, by:

1. Opening **iTunes / Preferences / Devices**.
2. A list with all the Devices will be show. Select the one's backUps you want to delete and click **Delete Backup**.

**Note** that **all** of the backUps of that iDevice will be deleted.

[image]

Comment: What if I have a folder but under tab from screenshot no devices are shown?

Comment: Does this answer also apply to macOS 10.11 (El Capitan)?

Comment: @EJMak It does. :)

Comment: where does this live in itunes new variation of itunes where music/podcast/... are separated?

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you are referring to ~/Library/Application Support/Mobile Sync/Backup.   This is the location where backups of iOS devices created by iTunes reside.   Each sub-folder represents a different iOS device.   If you delete this folder you will be unable to restore your iOS devices to their backed up state from iTunes.   if you wish to see a list of backups stored by iTunes, open iTunes, go to the iTunes menu > preferences.   Find the Devices tab in preferences and select it and you should see a list of device backups.

Comment: On macOS Sierra (10.12.5 (16F73)) it's located at `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup`