# Can I move Mobile Sync folder to another HD

Tags: ios, itunes, backup, imac, startup

Can I move my MobileSync folder to another HD on my iMac to free up space on my startup HD?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Mobile Sync - Backup and why is it taking so much space?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63207/what-is-mobile-sync-backup-and-why-is-it-taking-so-much-space)

Comment: Which folder/path are you referring to here?

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63207/what-is-mobile-sync-backup-and-why-is-it-taking-so-much-space. While you should not move the folder, you can follow the advice of the accepted answer to free up space from this folder.

Comment: I see no reason this is a dupe - connected, sure, but not a dupe as such. The linked question is 'what is it & why is it so big'. This is 'can I move it', to which the answer is yes. I suppose one may question *why* it needs to be moved, as in 'is this an XY question?', but it can be, if needed, so I see no reason it can't stand on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the folder to another drive, then use a symbolic link back to the original location, so iTunes can still find it.

A symbolic link is a bit like a shortcut or alias, that the system can use to target a file or folder in another location.
Because of the rather arcane method you'd need to employ in Terminal to generate them, I've always used a little freeware app that sets itself up as a Service in OS X, meaning you can access it through the right-click menu - [SymbolicLinker](https://github.com/nickzman/symboliclinker/releases)

After Installing this [reboot may be required if it doesn't immediately show in the right-click menu], the procedure would be

- Move your MobileSync folder to your new drive, Cmd/drag will move rather than copy.
- Right-click the folder in its new location, go to Services at the bottom of the menu, then Make Symbolic Link
- Cmd/drag the created link back to the original location in ~Library/Application Support/
- Change its name to remove the 'symlink' at the end, so it has the original name MobilSync
- Done.

Comment: Tetsujin is right, I follow his instructions & freed up 60Gb of space!, but his link to SymbolicLinker is broken; use this one
[http://download.cnet.com/SymbolicLinker/3000-18487_4-33926.html](http://download.cnet.com/SymbolicLinker/3000-18487_4-33926.html)

Comment: Even better place would be the official Github repo https://github.com/nickzman/symboliclinker/releases